# are $f$ and $g$ bounded function?

Tags: complex-analysis

$f$ and $g$ are entire function such that $|f^2+g^2|=1$ Then which of the following are correct?

1. $f$ and $g$ are constant.
2. $f$ and $g$ are bounded.
3. $f$ and $g$ have no zeroes on unit circle.
4. $ff'+gg'=0$

Well What I do is let $h(z)= f^2(z) + g^2(z)$ then clearly $h(z)$ is bounded entire hence constant by Liouville theorem, hence (4) is correct right?

Comment: Your answer for 4 is correct.  Can you think of any examples of (nonconstant, analytic) functions satisfying $f^2+g^2=1$?

Comment: I gotta know: who is Laluvulu?

Comment: @Jonas:yes $f(z)=\sqrt{z}$ and $g(z)=\sqrt{1-z}$, steve, I am lalu and my pet's name is vulu ;) :) directsum of me and my pet is laluvulu :)

Comment: @Mex: Those are not entire functions.  Trig identities are more useful here.

Comment: @SteveD Laluvulu, beats me!

Comment: ah I see, then $sin(z)$ and $cos(z)$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first option is wrong since for instance, $f(z) = \cos(z)$ and $g(z) = \sin(z)$.

The second option is wrong since for instance, $f(z) = \cos(z)$ and $g(z) = \sin(z)$.

The third option is wrong since for instance, $f(z) = \cos(\pi z)$ and $g(z) = \sin(\pi z)$. Note that $g(1) = 0$.

The fourth option is correct since $f^2 + g^2$ is again entire and by Liouville's theorem, we have that $f^2 + g^2 = c$, where $c$ is a constant such that $\lvert c \rvert = 1$. Hence, taking the derivative gives us $ff' + gg' = 0$.

Comment: @DaveRadcliffe Yes. A constant with magnitude $1$.

Comment: Extremely Thank you for nice answer!